# I suddenly can't see the tweets older than today

Tags: twitter, tweet

Last night everything was normal on Twitter. Today, when I logged on to Twitter, I could only see a few tweets and no more. I waited a few hours and retried only to realize that older tweets are not loaded whereas the new tweets are loaded. This is the screenshot of where the tweets end in the page:

[image]

Now I can only see the tweets tweeted in the last 8 hours. I tried this on my mobile phone and on another PC, and the result is the same.

When I open the profile of someone whom I follow, their tweets are shown properly.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Report the issue here: http://support.twitter.com/groups/32-something-s-not-working/topics/133-top-issues/articles/20143938-my-timeline-gets-cut-off-at-a-specific-date

Comment: Link rot happened...

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar seems like the took down the page. (Maybe because the issue doesn’t manifest itself anymore?)

Comment: I haven't faced the problem lately. Maybe you're right.

Comment: @Alex The link has been reported as invalid.  No replacement was found.  Up to you if you want to try to find an updated one.

Answer (score -1):

To preserve older tweets, consider [subscribing to your Twitter timeline RSS feed within a feed reader like Google Reader](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2012/04/archive-tweets-favorites-with-google.html). You can then browse through your older tweets within the feed reader.

Comment: Twitter killed the RSS feed a long time ago.

Comment: @al-e The answer was as of the date posted.

Comment: Undoubtedly true, but it is of little use now.

Answer (score -1):

The API will only load some max number of the most recent tweets to populate your timeline. Depending on how many people you follow, that could mean a days' worth or mere hours' worth of tweets. Sorry.

Comment: _Sorry_ for what?